# "ON the west of New York?" Is this preposition correct?

Tags: prepositions

I read an exercise of prepositions. Here is one sentence:

> Los Angeles is ____the west of New York.

You may choose one preposition from the following:

**from, on, to, in and of**

Is it correct to put the preposition ON into the sentence?

> Los Angeles is  **ON** the west of New York.

Answer (score 16):

In your sentence

> Los Angeles is *to* the west of New York.

is the correct answer.  You could think of "to" as replacing "towards" and also signifying a greater distance.

[image: here]
<sub>(source: [evrus.net](http://www.evrus.net/images/LA-NY-EVCharging-Map-900.jpg))</sub>

"On" can also be used to show direction, and sometimes implies a closer distance

> The Hudson River is *on* the west side of Manhattan.
>   The Hudson River is *to* the west of Manhattan.
>
> Newark is *to* the west of Manhattan.
>   Newark is not *on* the west side of Manhattan.

[image: here]

Answer (score 4):

The answer is ***to***.

You can use the construct *to the [direction] of* to indicate the position or location of something relative to something else, where [direction] is typically *left*, *right* or a cardinal direction (*south*, *north*, etc.)

You can also use *to [possessive] [direction]*; this is much more common with *left* and *right* than with cardinal directions.

Here are some examples:

- Los Angeles is to the west of New York.
- The book is to Joe's right.
- There is a tree to your left.

Comment: It's true that in OP's *exact* context, ***to*** is far more likely, but I think that's at least partly because *X is **on** the west of Y* might be taken to imply X actually lies *within* the boundary of Y (on the west side). I'm pretty sure ***on*** would be more common than ***to*** in your last example, where no such ambiguity is possible.

Comment: @FumbleFingers When I hear "on your left" I think of a tour guide pointing things out. I would probably say "to your left" rather than "on your left" in the tree instance.

Comment: @barbecue: Only ***Turn to** your left* works, but ***Look on** your right* is at least credible (***to*** is much more likely though). Anyway, [here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=door+on+your+left%2Cdoor+to+your+left%2Con+your+left+is%2Cto+your+left+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoor%20on%20your%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoor%20to%20your%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20your%20left%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20your%20left%20is%3B%2Cc0) a chart backing up my point re *door XX your left, XX your left is*, where ***on*** wins.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Note that bringing the [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=door+on+your+left%2Cdoor+to+your+left%2Con+your+left+is%2Cto+your+left+is&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdoor%20on%20your%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoor%20to%20your%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20your%20left%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20your%20left%20is%3B%2Cc0) to 2008 (the most recent it goes), brings "to your left" almost level with "on your left".

Comment: We can also look at "[tree to/on your left](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tree+on+your+left%2Ctree+to+your+left&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctree%20on%20your%20left%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctree%20to%20your%20left%3B%2Cc0)", where we see "to" has caught up by 2008. I'd say these are cases where either word is pretty typical.

Answer (score 4):

It's also acceptable to omit the preposition, and just say "Los Angeles is west of New York." This kind of usage is common in conversational speech.

Comment: While right, I think this should probably have been a comment rather than an answer. But to add to it anyway: This answer has the correct, idiomatic, phrase. If I hear "X is to the west of Y", I interpret that X is west of Y, but not by very much. Hence Newark is *to the west* of New York, whereas Los Angeles is *west* of New York.